# How do I display an animated gif in React Native?

Tags: react-native

How can I display an animated gif in react native.  This is what I've tried.

```
<Image source={{uri: "loading"}} />
```

It works fine with a `.png` file but when I use a `.gif` file it's blank. I read somewhere to try renaming the `.gif` to a `.png` but that just displays one frame of the animated gif with no animation.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

**For RN < 0.60**

By default the Gif images are not supported in android react native app.
You need to set use [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html) to display the gif images.
The code:

Edit your `android/app/build.gradle` file and add the following code:

```
dependencies: { 

    ...

    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.+'

    // For animated GIF support
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.+'

    // For WebP support, including animated WebP
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.+' 
}
```

then you need to bundle the app again, You can display the gif images in two ways like this.

```js
1-> <Image 
        source={require('./../images/load.gif')}  
        style={{width: 100, height: 100 }}
    />

2-> <Image 
        source={{uri: 'http://www.clicktorelease.com/code/gif/1.gif'}}  
        style={{width: 100, height:100 }} 
    />
```

**For RN >= 0.60**

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.12.0' //instead of

implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'   //use
```

I hope it is helpful to others,

Comment: For animated GIFs, `animated-base-support` doesn't work for me (RN 0.41.0), however `animated-gif` (the first one under WebP) works. This is what I ended up adding to my `build.gradle` file: `compile "com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.1.0"`

Comment: @RyanH. Do you have both `animated-base-support` *and* `animated-gif`? I wonder if `animated-base-support` is a basic requirement and `animated-gif` is just incorrectly grouped with webp.

Comment: @cedmans I only needed `animated-gif`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/38169519/305383

Comment: now **compile** has been replaced with **implementation**

Comment: fresco 3.0.0 was released two weeks ago and is now the suggested version, i.e. use com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:3.0.0'

Answer (score 38):

You need to add the extension and require it this way :

```js
<Image source={require('./path/to/image/loading.gif')} />
```

or

```js
<Image source={{uri: 'http://www.urltogif/image.gif'}} />
```

Comment: How do I link to a gif in my Images.xcassets?

Comment: RN does not use Images.xcassets anymore. You need to put them in a folder in your project and use a relative path to that file.

Comment: Major change from 0.13 to 0.14 : static images. You should use require with a relative path for local images.

Comment: Doens't work for Android as far as I know and tested.

Comment: @Orlando Doesn't work on Android 6.0 from my testing. Just see a static image (i.e. the first frame of the gif).

Comment: oh cool that extension!

Answer (score 36):

### For React Native 0.60 and higher

Open your `android/app/build.gradle` file and add following lines to first of `dependencies` section

```sh
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
```

And then

```
cd android
gradlew clean
react-native run-android
```

Comment: i Just used implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0' and after gradlew clean

Comment: I had to use `./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 32):

For me on **React native 0.65.1**
The solution in [react-native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.65/image#gif-and-webp-support-on-android) did not work
I had to use the latest version of Fresco:

`implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.5.0'`

Now GIF works on Android for me.

You can check Fresco latest from [their website](https://frescolib.org/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 12):

#### For Android You Need to Add Facebook's Fresco Library

React Native does not come with Gif support out of the box but you can add Facebook's Fresco library to add this support.

You should be able to simply add the following to your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.+'
```

**Specific Version Compatibility**

If you are having troubles or you want to use a static version (*highly* recommended), you can simply go to the following React Native documentation page and replace the `0.46` in the URL with the version of React Native you're running:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.46/image.html#gif-and-webp-support-on-android

Comment: the second part (using a static version) is vital actually, without using the right version I got a crash, switching the the stated version in docs fixed it

Comment: @BlueBot I'm all about Static Versioning. The less magic in dependency versions, the better. Ensures the least amount of surprises.

Comment: So, if React Native does not come with GIF support out of the box, why is it working for Apple/IOS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle

Answer (score 4):

[DylanVann / react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) is a nice alternative that supports GIFs for both Android (based on [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) rather than [fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)) and iOS ([SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)) with additional features that looks like:

```jsx
const YourImage = () => (
    <FastImage
        style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
        source={{
            uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1',
            headers: { Authorization: 'someAuthToken' },
            priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        }}
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use gif as background image than you can use

```
<ImageBackground
 source={yourSourceFile}
> 
 -- your content ---
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 3):

To add gif and WebP in your project you need some optional modules. If the RN version is <=0.59 then add the following lines in your `android/app/build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.10.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.10.0'
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.10.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.10.0'
}
```

If the RN version is 0.60 and greater then add the following lines in `android/app/build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.10.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.12.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.10.0'
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.10.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.10.0'
}
```

Comment: Great Where do you add that to your Expo app ?

Comment: @webmaster you can read this https://forums.expo.io/t/display-animated-gif/4940/6

Comment: Actually converted the .gif to a video file (mp4) solved my problem like this ;) no need to import things.. :)

Answer (score 3):

For `react-native": "0.68.2"` this version is working for me

```js
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'
```

Comment: Refer to the `FRESCO_VERSION` in this file ( https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/latest/ReactAndroid/gradle.properties ) to know which version to use with the latest React Native (Documentation: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image )

Answer (score 2):

I solve it by add source to FastImage

add to your app

```
yarn add react-native-fast-image
```

```js
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';


 
  <FastImage
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={{width: 70, height:70}}
       //===>   source={require('../images/<imageName>.gif')}
          //OR
       //===>   source={{uri: 'https://<YOUR_LINK>.gif'}}
        />
       )};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';

**step1 import from react narive  You Can Use (Image) Or (ImageBackground)  **


import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,ImageBackground} from 'react-native';





function LoadingUsers() {
    return(<View style={styles.LoadingView}>



**Step 2 require inside source ImageBackground **



<ImageBackground source={require('../assets/stickman.gif')} style={styles.Gif}><Text>Loading..</Text></ImageBackground>
</View>)
}
 


**Step 3 Set Width ANd height **


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    LoadingView:{
        flex:1,
    },
    Gif:{
        flex:1,
        width:"100%",
        height:"100%",
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center",
        backgroundColor:'#000',
    }
  
    });
    export default LoadingUsers ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Open project/android/app then build.gradle file and find dependencies and add this line(dependency for .gif)

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // For GIF image support
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.5.0'
    //or implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'
}
```

then in your react component you can pass any .gif or any gif url like so

```
const gifUrl = 'https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeic75wkaqvblmte523qkzdoe437onrwl3xgvy5argmh6uhmrn7g2wi'
...
return (
   <View>
      <Image source={{uri: gifUrl}} style={{width: 200, height: 200}} />
   </View>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

2024 update:

for react-native: 0.73.1

this worked for me:

```
// For animated GIF support
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:3.1.3'

// For WebP support, including animated WebP
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:3.1.3'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:3.1.3'
```

lower versions of fresco didn't work

Answer (score 0):

For `RN >= 0.66`

Edit your `android/app/build.gradle` file and add the following code:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In any case you need something else you could use also WebView for it

```
render(props) {
    const width = 220;
    const height = 135;
    const borderRadius = 15;
    const uri = 'https://c.tenor.com/0wj4ApfUlWUAAAAM/whatever-bank-stare.gif';
    // const uri = 'https://c.tenor.com/YwsCGem_MmQAAAAC/parks-and-rec-amy-poehler.gif',;
    // const uri = 'https://media.tenor.com/images/1c39f2d94b02d8c9366de265d0fba8a0/tenor.gif';

    return (
        <View
            style={{
                width,
                height,
                borderRadius: 15,
                overflow: 'hidden',
            }}>
            <WebView
                source={{
                    uri
                }}
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    width,
                    height,
                    borderRadius,
                }}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                injectedJavaScript={`
                        document.body.style.width = "${width}px";
                        document.body.style.height = "${height}px";
                        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "${'#fff'}";
                        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
                        const img = document.querySelector("img");
                        img.style.position = "absolute";
                        img.style.top = 0;
                        img.style.left = 0;
                        img.style.margin = "auto";
                        img.style[img.offsetWidth > img.offsetHeight ? 'width' : 'height'] = "100%";
                        img.style.borderRadius = "${borderRadius}px";
                   `}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

It will preserves the gif aspect ratio

Also, I did the same with the `<Image />`. For anyone need it:

```
function ChatImageGIF(props) {
    const maxWidth = 220;
    const maxHeight = 135;
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(maxWidth);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(maxHeight);
    const borderRadius = 15;

    Image.getSize(props.currentMessage.video, (w, h) => {
        const minWidth = Math.min(maxWidth, w);
        const minHeight = Math.min(maxHeight, h);
        const aspectRatio = (w < h ? w : h) / (w < h ? h : w);
        setWidth(w < h ? minHeight * aspectRatio : minWidth);
        setHeight(w > h ? minWidth * aspectRatio : minHeight);
    });

    return (
        <View
            style={{
                width,
                height,
                borderRadius: 15,
                overflow: 'hidden',
            }}>
            <Image
                source={{
                    uri: props.currentMessage.video,
                }}
                style={{
                    width,
                    height,
                    borderRadius,
                    resizeMode: 'contain',
                }}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a .gif file in react native there are some factors that have to be verified first, if your project is made with expo currently in SDK 48 use react native version '0.71.8' and in this case if you use the module from  of expo or react native you would only have to look for the normal image.gif as if you were using any other image like this:

> import { Image } from "expo-image";

or

> import { Image } from "react-native";

```
// USING EXPO
<Image source={require('../../../assets/Img/your-image.png')} contentFit="contain" style={{width: w, height: h}}/>


// USING REACT NATIVE
<Image source={require('../../../assets/Img/your-image.png')} style={{width: w, height: h, resizeMode: 'contain'}}/>
```

Greetings and I hope I have helped those who see this :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue in react native 0.73.3 . I finally solved the problem by updating android/app/build.gradle by adding few lines of code in dependencies section.
`implementation("com.facebook.fresco:fresco:3.1.3") implementation("com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:3.1.3")`
Always refer to fresco official site https://frescolib.org/docs/