# How to display GIF in react-native android app?

Tags: android, image, react-native, gif

I want to display a simple gif via URL in my Image tag in my android react-native app but when I start it no image is shown.
The code as provided in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html%20docs) does work only for iOS but not for android:

```
<Image
  style={styles.gif}
  source={{uri: 'http://38.media.tumblr.com/9e9bd08c6e2d10561dd1fb4197df4c4e/tumblr_mfqekpMktw1rn90umo1_500.gif'}}
/>
```

There was a similar question here but as already said this only works for iOS:
[How do I display an animated gif in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594783/how-do-i-display-an-animated-gif-in-react-native)
Regarding this commit it should work though:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/fcd7de5301655b39832d49908e5ca72ddaf91f7e

Comment: if you're simply loading GIF image through the link then why not use WebView?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> We made the core library smaller by making things like GIF support optional.

Because of that [we have to manually opt-in for gif support in Android](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html).
Add both of the following lines to your android/app/build.gradle file under dependencies:

```
compile "com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0"
compile "com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0"
```

So your dependencies section might look like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
  compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
  compile "com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0"
  compile "com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0"
```

This solves the problem for your debug build but if you want to solve it also in your release build at them moment you have to add the following line to your proguard-rules file:

```
-keep class com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.AnimatedFactoryImpl { public AnimatedFactoryImpl(com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.PlatformBitmapFactory, com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ExecutorSupplier); }
```

More information on this here: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1177

This was fixed with this [commit](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/commit/0d0c5757ff40eb9e9f23533c9798dcdde095ce86) and will be included in the next release.

Comment: when you say next release is that version 0.13.0? I just tried that release and the issue seems to be still present

Comment: `compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.+'`

Comment: this compile line is not working in latest react native version. Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: Release build is getting failed for react native .

Comment: To find the right compatible version to use just replace `0.46` with the version of React Native you're using and see what the docs say: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.46/image.html#gif-and-webp-support-on-android

Answer (score 17):

All of the above did not work for me with the latest React Native(v0.48). I had to add the following dependencies in my `android/app/build.gradle`

`compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.5.0'
 compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.5.0'`

Comment: @AdirZoari: React native support gif for ios by default.

Comment: To find the right compatible version to use just replace `0.46` with the version of React Native you're using and see what the docs say: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.46/image.html#gif-and-webp-support-on-android

Comment: add 'multiDexEnabled true' if multidex error as per https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/516

Comment: @TekesteKidanu Is there a way to play GIF only once into Android?

Answer (score 16):

if using RN Version .60 try adding below inside app build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
}
```

[Source](https://frescolib.org/docs/)

Comment: react-native docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#gif-and-webp-support-on-android

Answer (score 13):

You can add these dependencies. I am using this in version (v0.44.0):

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:0.14.1'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.14.1'
```

In version v0.50 you only need to add

`compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'`

Comment: @KartiikeyaBaleneni try the answer above, it seems to work for earlier versions.

Comment: To find the right compatible version to use just replace `0.46` with the version of React Native you're using and see what the docs say: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.46/image.html#gif-and-webp-support-on-android

Answer (score 11):

We upgraded to `"react-native": "^0.57.1"`, which stopped our animated gifs from playing; they just rendered the first frame of the animation as static images.

To correct for this, we included the following libraries:

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'
compile "com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0"

// (Only if supporting WebP.)
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.10.0'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.10.0'
```

Comment: This should be the most accepted answer as of now. Thanks @Mapsy

Comment: I faced gif issue in react native version 0.59.9 and it's solved by this answer. Thanks @Mapsy

Answer (score 5):

For the latest version of react-native '0.61.5' you need '2.0.0' Fresco Version ;

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
```

Comment: @staminna I actually worked on it when I was trying to convert my FYP in react-native and the above method worked for me. I got the above solution from git-hub and I don't remember from which issue. 

There could be many possibilities for this problem that's why this question got many answers. You can push your work on Github and share the link. I will look at it when i will get time.

Comment: I can see the .gif using chrome on the emulator, therefore I believe it's not a network problem

Comment: <Image source={{uri: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/ZFRGcQqAxEw9RB9IHm/giphy.gif'}} />

Comment: I think you have to save it in the react app locally.

Comment: Works for me on react-native version 0.61.4 too ;)

Answer (score 1):

From React Native [Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#gif-and-webp-support-on-android):

When building your own native code, GIF and WebP are not supported by default on Android.

You will need to add some optional modules in android/app/build.gradle, depending on the needs of your app.

```
dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:2.1.0'
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.0.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **RN 64.1** you need to use the newer version of fresco to support gif in Android

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.4.0'
// For animated GIF support
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.4.0'
// For WebP support, including animated WebP
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.4.0'
```

[frescolib ref](https://frescolib.org/docs/)

Comment: Gifs stopped animating when I updated to RN 0.66.3, your answer helped but I had to update from fresco 2.0.0 to 2.6.0, 2.4.0 would not work. Make sure to check the supplied link and get the most recent version!

Answer (score 0):

For me adding the dependencies like below **wasn't enough**:

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.9.0'
```

I also had to upgrade my gradle version in the file:

**android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**
like this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

and also my build tools version in the file:

**android/build.gradle** like this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

Comment: Is there a way to play GIF only once for Android?

Answer (score 0):

GIF and WebP are not supported in default Android. So add bellowed dependencies in app level build.gradle file of android project and synch.

```
// For animated GIF support
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.4.0'
// For WebP support, including animated WebP
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.4.0'
```