# React-Native: GIF Images not looping

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I have a strange problem.
I have some gif images in my project and some of them load and loop normally, others just loop once and stop. Any ideas why would this happen ? 
My dependencies:

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:0.14.1'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.14.1'
```

Updated to 1.0.0, but still the same outcome.

How i call the gif:

```
<Image source={require('./gif/Tree.gif')} />
```

Thank you !

React Native Version 0.45.1

Comment: check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594783/how-do-i-display-an-animated-gif-in-react-native
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169519/how-to-display-gif-in-react-native-android-app

Comment: @JigarShah I did check them. I don't think I missed anything. Some of the GIFs are displaying and looping. While others loop once and then stay as a static Image.

Comment: Change the code of
 node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTGIFImageDecoder.m


animation.repeatCount = loopCount == 0 ? HUGE_VALF : loopCount;

to

animation.repeatCount = loopCount == 0 ? 0 : loopCount;

try this.

Comment: Hmm. now the app crashes just before the gif would be rendered. And by crash I mean hard crash.

Comment: I fixed the crashing but the GIFs still do not loop. @ER.SHASHITIWARI

Comment: I updated to fresco 1.0.0 , but still the same

Comment: So you're saying some are looping and some are not? sounds like it's a problem with those gifs, not your app. Upload a gif [here](https://ezgif.com/loop-count) to change it's loop count and see if that helps (I believe 0 means infinite).