# GIF image not showing animation in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am facing the problem with gif image in react-native.How to use gif image in react native. This is my code and I have placed the image in the images.js file.

Comment: You forgot to post you code. Please add it

Comment: <Image source= {images.Profileload} /> it comes from images.js file this is code  Profileload : require('./img/Loading_icon.gif')

Comment: And so the image is shown but is not moving?

Comment: yes animation is not working

Answer (score 6):

Previously I fixed the issue of gif image displaying in ReactNative. 
You too fix this if you follow the following steps,

By default the Gif images are not supported in android react native app. You need to set use Fresco to display the gif images. The code:

```
Edit your android/app/build.gradle file and add the following code:


dependencies: { 
...
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.+'

// For animated GIF support
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.+'

// For WebP support, including animated WebP
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.+'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.+'
```

}

then you need to bundle the app again, You can display the gif images in two ways like this.

**For RN >= 0.60**

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.12.0' //instead of

 implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'   //use
1-> <Image 
    source={require('./../images/load.gif')}  
    style={{width: 100, height: 100 }}
/>

  2-> <Image 
    source={{uri: 'http://www.clicktorelease.com/code/gif/1.gif'}}  
    style={{width: 100, height:100 }} 
/>
```

I hope it is helpful to others,

Comment: Thank you so much. you have saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

Just like other assets image:

```
<Image
  source={require('./images/loading.gif')}
  style={{height: 200, width: 200}}
  resizeMode='contain'
/>
```

**Note**: [You need to turn on GIF support for Android version](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#gif-and-webp-support-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

use this,

```
<Image
  style={styles.gif}
  source={{uri: 'http://38.media.tumblr.com/9e9bd08c6e2d10561dd1fb4197df4c4e/tumblr_mfqekpMktw1rn90umo1_500.gif'}}
/>
```

make sure to add below dependency,

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:0.14.1'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.14.1'
```

for more details refer this ,
[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169519/how-to-display-gif-in-react-native-android-app) question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Image source={require('./img/ezgif.com-resize.gif')} />
```

//add that inside dependancy block in android/app/build.gradle

compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'

compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'

compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.3.0'

compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.3.0'

Answer (score 1):

**Add that inside dependancy block in android/app/build.gradle**

*For me react-native version 0.57.8. It is working for me.

compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'
   compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.10.0'
*

```
 <Image source={{ uri: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/NSI5d5LiHPxXCKDbob/giphy.gif' }}
style={{ height: 80, width: 60, }}
 />
```