# Gif image is not working in android in react native

Tags: android, react-native

*Animation is not working in gif image in android*

[image: Android gif image without animation]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display GIF in react-native android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169519/how-to-display-gif-in-react-native-android-app)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

please follow the details in the [FB docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#gif-and-webp-support-on-android) it will specify the required things that you need.

You will need to add some optional modules in android/app/build.gradle, depending on the needs of your app.

```
dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.3.0'
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.3.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.3.0'
}
```

Also, if you use GIF with ProGuard, you will need to add this rule in proguard-rules.pro :

```
-keep class com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.AnimatedFactoryImpl {
  public AnimatedFactoryImpl(com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.PlatformBitmapFactory, com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ExecutorSupplier);
}
```

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 41):

> For react native version>=0.60 :

When building your own native code, GIF and WebP are not supported by default on Android.

You will need to add some optional modules in `android/app/build.gradle`, depending on the needs of your app.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
```

> For latest react native version 0.66 :

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'
```

Comment: Where exactly are you supposed to put this? Do you first need to install a package?

Comment: Just put it in YourProject/android/app/build.gradle, under dependencies

Comment: This worked for me using react native 0.64.2

Comment: Not work after update react native 0.65 any update?

Comment: Not working for react native 0.66

Comment: Use `implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'` for RN 0.66

Comment: Thank you @AnnieTan I have added this in my answer.

Comment: Yes, working as well on RN 0.66 with `implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'`, Thanks @KishanBharda

Answer (score 13):

Update: react-native@0.57.0

```
// For animated GIF support
// ./android/app/build.gradle

implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.10.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'
```

Comment: i tried various libraries, just this works for me, react-version: 0.59.9, thanks

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/image#gif-and-webp-support-on-android

Answer (score 6):

For React Native version : 0.66.4

Add these below lines in android/app/build.gradle file,

```
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
    // For animated GIF support

 implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'
    // For WebP support, including animated WebP

 implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:2.0.0'

 implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.0.0'
```

And Use it like:

```
<Image
   source={require('../assets/splah.gif')}
   style={{ width: '100%',height:'100%' }}
/>
```

Comment: This works for me.    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.0",

Answer (score 5):

**Update for React Native version : 0.73**

As I understood, RN 0.73 uses fresco 3.1, so I had to change version in *./android/app/build.gradle* like that

```
// For animated GIF support
implementation ("com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:3.1.0")
```

That worked for me

Comment: Thanks this worked for me too. I am using RN 0.73.1

Comment: Looks like this is the solution for react native 0.73. This solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved my issue by doing this in android/app/build.gradle

> implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'

Answer (score 0):

**Add the Following line on android/app/build.gradle**

```
 dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.3.0'
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.3.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fresco updated it's versions so older versions are not working, for new versions -  [Visit fresco page here](https://frescolib.org/docs/index.html)

dependencies {

// For animated GIF support
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:3.1.3'

// For WebP support, including animated WebP
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:3.1.3'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:3.1.3'

// For WebP support, without animations
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:3.1.3'

// Provide the Android support library (you might already have this or a similar dependency)
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.1'
}