# React Native icon and gif sometimes wont see android sdk 19 and lower

Tags: android, react-native

Some icon and gif not all icon and gif sometimes wont see android sdk 19 and lower devices, I tried to change fresco version in build.gradle but did not work my fresco version is:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.12.0'
implementation "com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.12.0"
```

My RN version is 0.59.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58283939/8182248 this may help you.

Comment: I tried that solution but wont work my rn version is 0.59