# How to display an animated Gif in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Before you link me to another question similar to this one, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594783/how-do-i-display-an-animated-gif-in-react-native) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169519/how-to-display-gif-in-react-native-android-app). I will say that I have done exactly what the answers said, but my gif won't animate as it should (It is displayed though).

Here is what I've done in a function, which is displayed through the main App function  Stack.Screen within a NavigationContainer and Stack.Navigator. (I'm using React Navigation to move across screens, the context here is that a button is pressed and it displays the contents of the DetailsScreen function)

```
function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {  
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 2, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Image source={require('./src/gif/moving.gif')} />
      <Text>Here is a gif</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

This displays the first still image of my gif, but doesn't animate it.

I also already went ahead and placed the implementations in the build.gradle dependencies, but it didn't do anything for me. I have a feeling the problem lies there.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.+'

// For animated GIF support
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.+'

// For WebP support, including animated WebP
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.+'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.+'
```

(I already checked fresco's new implementation version 2, but it still didn't help. I also tried changing from a specific version, still doesn't work)

I am using React Native version 0.67. (I tried starting it again while downgrading react-native to 0.66 and it still doesn't work.)

[image: import com]

Also, not sure if this has to do with anything in this screenshot here, this is what I had by default and gave me this error message as soon as I opened the file, but the program launches just fine even with that on

Doing it normally in the main App() function starting first displays the gif, but still remains as a still image.

What should I do? I mean... what else can I do?

Edit:

I found the solution to the problem... it was a simple case of just cold booting the emulator I was using from android studio.

However, Tadej's answer is valid, as the view style aligning messes up the gif a bit. If you are having a similar problem and the answer doesn't help, try cold booting your emulator, or even reinstall a newer one... or alternatively, use a real android phone to test these sorts of things.

Anyway, thanks a lot for the help Tadej ! I hope this question has helped others in my situation.

Tadej Slemenšek

Comment: Feel free to leave a comment asking a question about what I've done, or where something is; I can provide additional information for better clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Setting height and width on Image prop did not show the gif. So I flexed it and added maxWidth and maxHeight.

```
const imageUrl = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/xT0xeCCINrlk96yc0w/giphy.gif';
const App = () => {

  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Image style={{flex: 1, maxWidth: width, maxHeight: width}} source={{uri: imageUrl}}/>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Strange, I did the equivalent as you in my function, I also used your link and did a uri just in case it wasn't a problem with my local gif, and then I tried doing exactly the same thing as you, with the "const App = () => {". But I still don't see the gif move, but its still displayed, its still a non-moving image.

Can I see the contents of your package.js? Maybe I'm missing some modules..

Comment: I created a fresh project. Are you using Android or iOS? Beacuse on Android you have to do some extra things. Checkout image component documentation on React Native page. Its all listed there.

Comment: I've edited my post regarding your response, is my build.gradle dependencies set correctly for supporting animated images?

Comment: Nevermind, I just found the solution. After waking up from bed, I had the idea of maybe cold booting my android emulator... then when I started the react-native app, the gif just started moving. Nice.

Comment: Oh ok. Try a real device next time :D

Comment: Haha.. Yeah. That is a better idea, I should just go ahead and buy a phone for this sort of thing x) Thanks a lot for your help though! What I was doing with the style in View actually was making the gif not show up at all, so your answer should help those who are going through similar problems