# Gif not working in React Native iOS

Tags: ios, image, reactjs, react-native

I'm Using react 15.2.1 and react-native 0.30.0

I checked out [How do I display an animated gif in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594783/how-do-i-display-an-animated-gif-in-react-native) and followed the instructions.

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'http://i.giphy.com/l41YiEvBtjGKNlzby.gif'
       style={{ height: 250, width: 250 }} />
```

Also tried

```
<Image source={require('./path/to.gif')}
       style={{ height: 250, width: 250 }} />
```

But the gif isn't showing. If I switch out the link for an image it works fine.

I checked this working example https://rnplay.org/apps/739mzQ but can't test it with 0.30.0 so I'm wondering if something has changed since then.

Comment: did you resolve? Some Giphy images display for me and some don't

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add gif to your project and use require function.

Comment: here is the link to solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594783/how-do-i-display-an-animated-gif-in-react-native/40717686#40717686

Answer (score 0):

> please try this example

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,  View} from 'react-native';
const SplashGif = require('./images/Wallpaper.gif');

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { container, imageStyles } = styles;
    return (
      <View style={container}>
        <Image source={SplashGif} style={imageStyles} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  imageStyles: {
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image,Text, View} from 'react-native';
const Splash = require('./images/testGif.gif')

class SplashSrceen extends Component {

  render() {
    const { container, splashgif } = styles;
    return (
      <View style={container}>
        <Image source={Splash} style={splashgif} />
        <Text>or</Text>
        <Image source={{uri:'https://media.tenor.com/images/0a1652de311806ce55820a7115993853/tenor.gif'}}style={splashgif} />
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  splashgif: {
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    width: '100%',
    height: '50%'
  }
});

export default SplashSrceen ;
```

**Android**

To correct for this, we included the following libraries:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.10.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'
}
```