# How to play a gif using ImageBackground in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-native

I have a GIF background image that I am rendering using react-native's ImageBackground component. The only issue is that the gif is not running, it becomes static.

When I use the Image component everything works fine, but I need to use the ImageBackground component

```
    <ImageBackground
       source= {require('../../assets/img/initial_wallpaper.gif')} 
       style={{flex:1}} >                

    </ImageBackground>
```

Using the code above the GIF renders statically. When I use the online expo util to test this it works fine there with the exact same code. But when I implement this in my react-native code base it does not work. Any   insight will be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: if your gif is not animating, there might be a problem with the gif.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display an animated gif in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594783/how-do-i-display-an-animated-gif-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594783/how-do-i-display-an-animated-gif-in-react-native) question on the same topic. From that, I'd guess you're running on Android? The following should help you resolve your problem:

> Edit your android/app/build.gradle file and add the following code:
>
> ```
> dependencies: { 
>
>     ...
>
>     compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.+'
>
>     // For animated GIF support
>     compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.+'
>
>     // For WebP support, including animated WebP
>     compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.+'
>     compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.+' 
> }
> ```
>
> then you need to bundle the app again, You can display the gif images
>   in two ways like this.
>
> ```
> 1-> <Image 
>         source={require('./../images/load.gif')}  
>         style={{width: 100, height: 100 }}
>     />
>
> 2-> <Image 
>         source={{uri: 'http://www.clicktorelease.com/code/gif/1.gif'}}  
>         style={{width: 100, height:100 }} 
>     />
> ```

Comment: I need to use ImageBackground, as it is a background Image.

Comment: Okay, apparently the dependencies I used caused the issue. Weird I followed the same thing you are showing me here from react native site. Except I am using ImageBackground. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

**GIF and WebP support on Android**

> When building your own native code, GIF and WebP are not supported by
>   default on Android.
>
> You will need to add some optional modules in
>   `android/app/build.gradle`, depending on the needs of your app.

```
dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.10.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.12.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.10.0'
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.10.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.10.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for others like me looking for the solution in **RN Version 0.60** try adding below inside app build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.12.0' //instead of

implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'   //use
```