# React native set GIF as android/ios device wallpaper

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using react-native-wallpaper-manager library for setting an image(.jpg, .png) as my Android/iOS devices wallpaper. Now I want to set a GIF image (or animated image) as my wallpaper. Can you guys recommend me some react libraries to complete that task?

Comment: android example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57453134/how-to-play-a-gif-using-imagebackground-in-react-native

Comment: That's not what I meant. I displayed the gif successfully in the app and it worked. But my question is that I cannot set that GIF as my wallpaper of my device home screen.

Comment: iOS devices don't support animated gifs as wallpaper. iOS apps cannot set the wallpaper.

Comment: then how about android, mate??? how can I do that by using react native libs?