# React Native Image non-looping animated gif lost when application sent to background

Tags: react-native, animated-gif

As can be seen from [this snack](https://snack.expo.io/@mehmetkaplan/51919a), I embedded 2 identical animated gifs back to back.

The first one that loops for ever functions as expected.

But the second, the non-looping animated gif is lost when the application is sent to background and retrieved back to foreground.

Is there anything that can be done to avoid this?

```js
import testAniGif from '../assets/test.gif';
import testAniGif2 from '../assets/test2.gif';

export default function AssetExample() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={testAniGif} />
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={testAniGif2} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to implement proper syntax for Image attribute

```
<Image style={styles.logo} source={require(testAniGif)} />
<Image style={styles.logo} source={require(testAniGif2)} />
```

Have a look Image syntax https://reactnative.dev/docs/image

For better understanding you can follow this answer too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40717686/3840093