# Using custom gif as a loading icon within <ActivityIndicator> using react-native

Tags: react-native

I am currently attempting to code an app in react native for an android device. I have created a custom loading component and am using the  to show a loading icon.

But, I want to use a custom gif loading icon that contains my app's colours. I have looked but I cannot seem to find anything, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react native does not support gif feature in its raw form. However, in order to reach what you want and use gifs in the application, you can take a look at the accepted answer on the subject;

[How do I display an animated gif in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594783/how-do-i-display-an-animated-gif-in-react-native)

Then all you need to do is to use Image component instead of ActivityIndicator. And passing the relevant gif information to the image component.