# Local gif file is not showing in android in react native

Tags: android, react-native

i tried the below code.

```
<ImageBackground
            source={require('../../Assets/Pharmaclouds.gif')}
            style={logoStyle}
        />
```

i can get gif working on ios but not working on android.

Comment: Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40717686/8196025)?

Answer (score 0):

**For React Native 0.60 and higher**

Open android/app/build.gradle file and add following lines to first of `dependencies` section

```
dependencies: { 

...

compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.+'

// For animated GIF support
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.+'

// For WebP support, including animated WebP
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.+'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.+' 
}
```

Comment: implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'

i added this two lines, but still not working for android.

Comment: Please try Image instead of ImageBackground.