# How to add gif in react-native appplication

Tags: react-native, android-animation, animated-gif

how to add gif in background in react native

How can I display an animated gif in react native. This is what I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a complete answer to this question in this link:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594783/how-do-i-display-an-animated-gif-in-react-native][1]